# Not able to type in input due to its parent <div.container-fluid> has CSS property: overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, cypress

Not able to type because its parent <div.container-fluid> has CSS property: overflow: hidden and an effective width and height of: 1600 x 0 pixels.

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.

```
cy.xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-0"]').type('Rest')
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `{force: true}` with `type`:

```js
cy.xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-0"]').type('Rest',{force: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like an animation problem. Try adding a visibility check

```js
cy.xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-0"]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .type('Rest')
```